# Blade not showing content in blade after @include - Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

I'm trying to switch master layouts based on http referer. I'm currently pulling the correct template but the content within the blade is not being shown -- no errors. $layout is passing properly because the template changes based on referer. This 404 blade is the only issue. Other blades pull into layouts just fine.

routes.php

```
App::missing(function($exception) {
    $referer = URL::previous();
    $layout = (strpos($referer,'ext')) ? 'layouts.ext.master' : 'layouts.master';
    return Response::view('error-404', compact('layout'), 404);
});
```

error-404.blade.php

```
@include($layout)

@section('page_content')
    content...
@stop
```

Layout (both /layouts/ext/master.blade.php and /layouts/master.blade.php contain html wrap.)

```
@yield('page_content')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@extends('layouts.ext.master')` instead of `@include('layouts.ext.master')`

Comment: `Error in exception handler: View [@extends('layouts.master')] not found.` Is it not being read due to how include handles? layouts.master does exist

Comment: You are correct, but weren't as descriptive as you could be. If you update your answer to explain why @include shouldn't be used, but rather @extends that would be helpful. `@include($layout)` becomes `@extends($layout)`

Answer (score -1):

please use

```
return View::make('error-404', compact('layout'));
```